# How to use options in discord.py?

Tags: discord.py, bots

I'm working on a discord bot that can send random memes, and I wanted to add a command for continuous feed according to a the amount of memes the user wants, for example /feed number:15, would send 15 memes.

The problem is how to make the option input work on the command, I've find some videos that helped me a little, but due to the other commands being híbrido commands, I can figure out how to make this one working.

This is what's I have so far:

```
@bot.hybrid_command(name = "feed", with_app_command = True, description = "Feeds a specific number of memes")

@app_commands.guilds(discord.Object(id = guild_id))

async def test1(interaction: discord.Interaction, number: int):

    await interaction.response.send_message("It's working!")
```

The await line, obviously won't do any feed this way, I know, I did the feed part separated and it works, but I just did it this way for testing, so if I type the command and enter a number, it should return me "It's working!", But that never happens, I suppose it's maybe something to do with híbrido commands, but I really don't know, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the input option is the problem, because I see nothing wrong with it, but the thing that is surely wrong is that you're naming the first argument of the hybrid command `interaction`, which is wrong and can create confusion; the actual argument it should be is `context` or `ctx`. And that object is a [discord.ext.commands.Context](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20context#discord.ext.commands.Context) object.

You should rename it to `ctx` to avoid confusion.

```py
@bot.hybrid_command(name = "feed", with_app_command = True, description = "Feeds a specific number of memes")
@app_commands.guilds(discord.Object(id = guild_id))
async def test1(ctx: commands.Context, number: int):
    await ctx.send("It's working!")
```

You may want to see the official example [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#hybrid-commands)